# NHibernate IQueryOver where clause with a collection

Tags: nhibernate

I'm attemping to do a simple check for an empty collection in an NHIbernate Query. Here's my code:

```
var query = QueryNotDeleted().Where(x=>x.Markets.Count() > 0);
```

QueryNotDeleted returns an IQueryOver.  The above line throws an error (Unrecognised method call in epression x.Markets.Count()) because it doesn't recognize the Count() in the query.

I tried

```
var query = QueryNotDeleted().Where(x=>x.Markets != null);
```

But unfortunately, Markets is never NULL, so I have to test for a count instead of it being null to get the records I want.

How can I get this "count" syntax correct so that it excludes records where the Markets property is empty?

Comment: Do you know the resulting SQL you're hoping for? Do you want the Markets collection eagerly loaded?

Comment: Try Where(x => !x.Markets.Any())

Comment: Are you sure you get back an iQueryOver? For me `x=>x.Markets.Count()` should not compile!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get it to work using:

```
query.RootCriteria.CreateAlias("Markets", "m", JoinType.LeftOuterJoin);
```

and then

```
query.RootCriteria.Add(Restrictions.IsNotNull("m.Id"));
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly you want to get a list of records that don't have corresponding children?

If I wanted to get a list of `Orders` that have no `OrderItems` using QueryOver then I would do something like:-

```
var orders = session.QueryOver<Order>()
  .Left.JoinQueryOver(w => w.Items)
  .Where(w => w.Order.Id == null);
```

If this is not the right answer then please can you submit the SQL you are trying to run and the parent/children mappings/.

Comment: This looks like it might work, though I was able to figure it out using 

    query.RootCriteria.Add(Restrictions.IsNotNull("m.Id"));